# Django won't connect to remote RDS

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql, amazon-rds

When I run 'python manage.py runserver', I get:

> File
>   "/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/dashboard-server-PG7390RB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py",
>   line 176, in get_new_connection
>       connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)   File "/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/dashboard-server-PG7390RB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py",
>   line 130, in connect
>       conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) " to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known name "rdsaddress.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com

This happened when I updated iterm2, but downgrading did not fix it.
I am able to successfully connect to the database using Postico.
I am unable to connect to a similar rds using Django as well.
I deleted my repository and repulled...

Not sure what to do next.

Comment: Does your DNS successfully resolve the DB hostname?

Comment: Can you connect to the database using `psql`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing your connection code, but it should look a little like this:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=your_database user=postgres password=xxxx host=127.0.0.1 port=5432")
```

The error complains about nodename nor servername provided, hence my inclination to look at your connection string.

Comment: Ha, turns out that it was a bad config file, copied over from Slack with hidden characters